# OpenTelemetry AWS XRay UDP

Tags: go, aws-sdk, open-telemetry, aws-xray

I'm trying to write data to the **awsxrayreceiver**. The data is from the trace segment.

Here are the steps that I did:

- Getting the trace summaries
- Using the trace IDs from the trace summary to do the batch get traces
- Sending the trace segment document by converting it to a `[]byte`

But I'm getting some errors when sending data. The UDP port is already accessible.

```json
{"kind": "receiver", "name": "awsxray", "pipeline": "traces", "error": "unable to split incoming data as header and segment, incoming bytes: [88]"}
{"kind": "receiver", "name": "awsxray", "pipeline": "traces", "error": "read from UDP socket: read udp [::]:2000: use of closed network connection"}
```

Even tried to check if the connection will succeed.

```
nc -vzu ip_address 2000

Result: Connection to ip_address 2000 port [udp/*] succeeded!
```

Is there something wrong with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is likely due to an error occurring while splitting the header and body due to a missing separator character. The error is coming from [this function](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/4dd1595a0f4d3ada8f400a9efef5969227b8f1c0/receiver/awsxrayreceiver/internal/tracesegment/util.go#L34) that separates the X-Ray segment header and body using a newline character as the separator. It seems the error may be caused by incorrectly formatted data being sent to the X-Ray receiver (see [these tests for an example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/4dd1595a0f4d3ada8f400a9efef5969227b8f1c0/receiver/awsxrayreceiver/internal/tracesegment/util_test.go#L26)).

The second error is a network error that can occur while [reading from the UDP poller](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/eb3052b93bdbca05d2f8eae78dbe72b4e551918d/receiver/awsxrayreceiver/internal/udppoller/poller.go#L154). There may be multiple reasons behind this issue, but perhaps ensure that the connection is not being closed early or before all the data is sent to the receiver.

Comment: Thanks for this. I already added the `{"format":"json", "version":1}` and it seems to be working now :)